# DLL for basic math operations

Tags: c#, beginner, .net, library

I've written a simple C# class to use as a dll for simple math calculations: addition, subtraction, division, and multiplication.

How can I improve this code, specifically for addition and multiplication? I've tested it with a C# GUI and a VB.NET GUI. I've tried it with VS 2005, 2008, 2010, 2012, and the Community Editions as well.

Class1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace my_class
{
    public class Class1
    {

       public static double addfunc(double num1, double num2)
       {
         return (num1 + num2);
       }

       public static double subfunc(double num1, double num2)
       {
         return (num1 - num2)
       }

       public static double divfunc(double num1, double num2)
       {
         return num1/num2;
       }

       public static double mulfunc(double num1, double num2)
       {
         return num1*num2;
       }

   }
}
```

Here is the code and screenshot of the working example:

Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace test_dll
 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
      public Form1()
      {
        InitializeComponent();
      }


      double num1, num2;
      double add;
      double sub;
      double multi = 1.0 ;
      double div = 1.0 ;

      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      { 
        num1 = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        num2 = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        add = my_class.Class1.addfunc(num1,num2);
        MessageBox.Show(add.ToString());
      }

      private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        num1 = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        num2 = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        sub = my_class.Class1.subfunc(num1,num2);
        MessageBox.Show(sub.ToString());
      }

      private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        num1 = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        num2 = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        multi = my_class.Class1.mulfunc(num1,num2);
        MessageBox.Show(multi.ToString());
      }

      private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        num1 = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        num2 = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        div = my_class.Class1.divfunc(num1, num2);
        MessageBox.Show(div.ToString());
      }
  }
}
```

[image: Working example using C#]

Comment: And why would you want to use external library instead of, you know, actually calling `num1 + num2` in your `Form1` class? Can you elaborate? What is your goal?

Comment: @NikitaB Dynamic link libraries (DLL) can be used store data, or store windows elements like **special dialog boxes** in a single file that will be useful to many programs. That developed DLL can reused in many programming language projects with a ease.

Comment: yes, but how is storing default math operations in dll is useful to anyone?

Comment: @NikitaB Yes I agreed .Here I've posted these code snippets to show that develop class library is easy and how to extract and use the functions of a dll file if a proper documentation is provided with it. Here I have included simple mathematical operations to it to explain it in a simple manner!

Comment: @Dannnno Now added the rest of the code for **Form1.cs**

Comment: I've edited your post to be more understandable, and also put the image back. Can you please update your image to show the most recent version of your program?  I've also retracted my close vote and down vote, as I think that there is a useful review in here.

Comment: This question is confusing... You're asking for feedback, but there's hardly anything interesting going on in your code. Then, in a comment, you're talking about 'showing that developing a class library is easy', which sounds like you're writing some kind of tutorial. What sort of feedback are you looking for exactly?

Comment: @Pieter Witvoet I've posted this because  sharering my little knowledge about DLL's . I've  encountered many failures and successes while testing this library. If the post is silly or unsuitable you have the power to down-vote it. You're knowing about this better than me you can delete the post or mark as moderator attention. Any up-vote or down-vote doesn't matter. If this thing is confusing you have the power to mark it down.

Comment: P.S.  This looks more like an executable than a dynamic link library since it has a GUI and all.

Comment: @Hosch250 I've developed first **Class1.cs** as class library on a separate VS project. Then it use it in  C# GUI project ,(**Form1.cs** included in the  C# GUI) . I've added generated **my_class.dll** as a reference in the C# GUI project!

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense with the "DLL" comments now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please be consistent:

```
public static double addfunc(double num1, double num2)
{
  return (num1 + num2);
}

public static double mulfunc(double num1, double num2)
{
  return num1*num2;
}
```

In one method, you use parenthesis around the expression, and in another, you don't.  In one method, you use spaces around the operator; in the other, you don't.

These methods could also be improved by using C# naming conventions: `addfunc` should be named with PascalCase as `AddFunc` at a minimum--writing out the full word "function" wouldn't hurt (although technically, this is called a "method" in C#).

---

Your indentation could also be improved.  Use a consistent 4 spaces (or 2 spaces, or 1 tab, if you prefer--4 spaces is the international default, however):

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace test_dll
 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
      public Form1()
      {
        InitializeComponent();
      }

      ...
    }
 }
```

Also, name your namespace and form something descriptive, rather than `test_dll` and `Form1`

---

More inconsistency here:

```
double num1, num2;
double add;
double sub;
double multi = 1.0 ;
double div = 1.0 ;
```

Why do you assign some of the values, but not others?  Why do you have spaces before some of your semi-colons?  Why aren't these explicitly stated to have  `private` scope, instead of trusting that the maintainer knows this?  I do like how you separated the values for the end result from the two input values, however--that shows more clearly that these values are not inputs.

---

Now this is a much more serious problem:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
  num1 = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
  num2 = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
  add = my_class.Class1.addfunc(num1,num2);
  MessageBox.Show(add.ToString());
}
```

First of all, why do you have `add` as a private field?  You never use the value anywhere else other than this method.  You should scope that tighter to show exactly where it is used.  Also, even if you did use it somewhere else, the value is only refreshed when you click the `add` button, so you have the potential to be working with outdated data.  There is a similar problem with `num1` and `num2`--even though you update these every time a button is pressed, you only use the value you read in the method for that button, and no where else; these too should be local variables.

Second, guess what happens if I type `test` in the textbox?  `double.Parse` will crash.  You should use [`double.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Thirdly (naming again), how do you expect me to know that this method is for the add function without reading it?  Suppose you just hired me, and I was handling a bug report (coming up in just a bit) in the division method?  I now have to spend four times as much time finding the bug and fixing it if I start at the top of the file and work my way down, instead of just reading the method signatures.

Fourthly, your button handlers are all incredibly [WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself#DRY_vs_WET_solutions).  You should consider doing something like this:

```
private void AddClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var result = GetResult(MathHelpers.AddFunction);
    MessageBox.Show(result);
}

private double GetResult(Func<double, double, double> computingFunction)
{
    var num1 = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    var num2 = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
    return computingFunction(num1, num2);
}
```

Using a delegate for that one step that changes makes this code much cleaner to read and maintain; if, for example, you had a bug in the code to read the values from the textboxes, you had to fix it in 8 separate places--once for each textbox for each operation.

Finally, a value divided by `0` is most definitely not infinity.  It is undefined.  Consider, for example, if `1 / 0 == Infinity` and `2 / 0 == Infinity`.  Now, we can say that `1 / 0 == 2 / 0`, and that `1 == 2`.  Clearly not true.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer. I've learned a lot from this answer. I'll add your suggestions to this class library!

Comment: Glad it helped.